# Is there any way to handle 4** series error codes in Videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

When using Videoview, I'm passing some random video id in the url which gives call back to

mVideoView.setOnErrorListener((mediaPlayer, what, extra) where the value of 'extra' is -1005.Is this error code similar to 404 ? If not, is there any value of 'extra' equivalent to 404 ?

I am expecting if the call back can have something so that i can handle for 404 or similar to 404 error code.